# Proving a property of Matrices

Tags: matrices

**The matrix $A$ has $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue with $e$ as a corresponding eigenvector.**

**Show that if $A$ is non-singular then $\lambda\neq 0$**

**Attempt**

$$Ae=\lambda e$$

$$A^{-1}Ae=A^{-1}\lambda e$$

$$\lambda^{-1}e=A^{-1}e$$

$\lambda$ cannot be $0$ because then $\lambda^{-1}e$ will be undefined.

Is this correct?

**Answer**

$\lambda=0$ and $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. This Implies the determinant of $A$ is $0$ which contradicts the data.

Can somebody explain how $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ was obtained?

Comment: If $A$ is singular $A^{-1}$ does not exist.  If you want to do a proof by contradiction, that is fine, but say so at the outset.

Comment: I am happy with any kind of proof.

Comment: If $Ae=0, A$ is singular.

Comment: Yes. I am a little confused over that part. What relationship is between Ae and det(A)*e? Like by just looking at Ae=0, why our conclusions regarding detA accurate? Is it because A =0 in that case?

Comment: if $Ae = \mathbf 0, A$ has a non-trival kernel.  Or, there exists a non-trivial combination of the vectors in $A$ that sum to $\mathbf 0$  Or, $\det(A) =0$  All of which are implications of singular matrices.

Comment: Please see this if I got it correct. If all the combination of the (column vectors, technically range space of matrix) vectors in a matrix sum up to 0, then determinant of that matrix equals 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning that you gave doesn't quite make sense because you divided by $\lambda$ before knowing that it was non-zero.

But you were already essentially done there, because **an eigenvector is nonzero by definition**.  Thus when you see that $$e = A^{-1}Ae = A^{-1}\lambda e$$ you conclude that $\lambda \not= 0$ immediately, since otherwise the arbitrary associated eigenvector $e$ would have to be $0$.

Note that it's not just convention that eigenvectors are defined as nonzero:  the meaning and application of eigenvalues (which are really really important!!) would fall apart if we allowed $0$ to be an eigenvector, since then $A\mathbf0 = \lambda \mathbf 0$ would be valid for all $\lambda$, and every matrix would have every scalar as a eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is diagonalizable then

$$
A = U\Lambda U^{-1}
$$

with $\Lambda = {\rm diag}\{ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots \}$. Thererore

$$
\det A = \det(U \Lambda U^{-1}) = (\det U)(\det \Lambda)(\det U^{-1}) = \frac{\det U}{\det U}\det \Lambda = \lambda_1\lambda_2 \cdots
$$

If $A$ is invertible, then $\det A \not = 0$, this means that $\lambda_1\lambda_2  \cdots \not = 0$, or equivalently $\lambda_i \not= 0$

Comment: what if $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: @DougM Wouldn't that imply that it is not possible to find $\lambda$ to begin with?

Comment: consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, A$ is not diagonalizable, but $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigevector with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: @DougM You're right, in this case is clearly imposible to define $U^{-1}$. I will leave this answer in case OP finds it somehow useful, otherwise I will delete it. Thanks

Comment: I found it a lot helpful but considering the counter example that@DougM cited, I don't think I would be able to use in class.

Answer (score 0):

$Ae = \lambda e$

if $\lambda = 0, Ae = \mathbf 0.$  Hence $A$ is singular.

And I would be inclined to end it there.  But, if you want to put on belt and suspenders,

$Ae = \mathbf 0$ implies that there is a linear combination of the column vectors in $A$ such that $e_1 v_1 + e_2 v_2 \cdots e_kv_k = \mathbf 0$ and the columns of $A$ are not linearly independent.

Where does
$\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ come from?

$Av = \lambda v\\
Av = \lambda I v\\
Av- \lambda I v = \mathbf 0\\
(A- \lambda I) v = \mathbf 0$

$(A- \lambda I)$ is singular

$\det (A - \lambda I) = 0$

Comment: So $A-\lambda I$ is always singular?

Comment: Yes, in fact $A - \lambda I$ is singular if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.